# Summing up values by calling a method of objects in a vector in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a nicer way to write this code in C++11?

```
int RawSheet::getNumberOfCities() const
{
    int n = 0;
    for (const auto &c : countries) {
        n += c.getNumberOfCities();
    }
    return n;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of the containers contents? I need it so my answer for you can compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) with a lambda callback:

```
#include <algorithm>

int RawSheet::getNumberOfCities() const
{
    return std::accumulate(countries.begin(), countries.end(), 0, [] (RawSheet const& op1, RawSheet const& op2)
    {
        return op1.getNumberOfCities() + op2.getNumberOfCities();
    });
}
```

Comment: std::accumulate doesn't call `c.getNumberOfCities()` though, you'd need to add an appropriate binary operation/lambda as the fourth parameter to made sure the correct value is accumulated.

Comment: @0x499602D2: `accumulate` also need an "init" value (probably 0, in this case) as its third parameter.

Comment: @0x499602D2, the function/lambda you need to pass actually takes two parameters, see here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate

Comment: @TimoGeusch What types should those parameters be? And what should I compute inside the lambda? I'm lost.